# Shiny does not render uiOutput data in modules

Tags: r, shiny

I have this code:

```
columnSelectorUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  return(
    wellPanel(
      h4("Select columns"),
      uiOutput(ns("tab"))
    ))
}

columnSelectorServer <- function(input, output, session) {
  print("XXX")
  state <- reactiveValues()
  print(renderUI({h2("hello")}))
  print(output)
  output$tab <- renderUI({div(HTML("hello"))})
}
```

What I see is that:

- XXX is printed, so the server function is called
- the h4 "selected columns" is rendered
- the uiOutput element is rendered, but not its content.

`<div id="columnSelector-tab" class="shiny-html-output shiny-bound-output"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Solved: I was missing a ns() call in the top-level widget when it called the UI component.